# Trying to install Cisco Jabber: "Error 1320. The specified path is too long"

Tags: windows-7, path, cisco-jabber

I am trying to install Cisco Jabber 11.8.4 Build 52954 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. During the installation, I get the error message:

> Error 1320. The specified path is too long
>   C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Sennheiser

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

- Move `C:\ProgramData\Application Data` to some of the folder
- Retry installing Cisco Jabber

It will create a new folder in `C:\ProgramData` containing:

```
Application Data
└───Sennheiser
    └───SDKCore
        ├───Logs
        └───PDS
                SecomSFSDK.dat [610 bytes]
```

You can rename `Application Data` (or move it somewhere else), and move the original `Application Data` back to `C:\ProgramData\Application Data`.

---

In my case, `SecomSFSDK.dat` contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SeComSFSDK>
    <PortNumber>8001</PortNumber>
    <LogToFile>No</LogToFile>
    <SupportedVID Count="2">
        <VID>0x1395</VID>
        <VID>0x1A17</VID>
    </SupportedVID>
    <AMSupportedHS Count="6">
    <HeadsetModel>Sennheiser USB-DHSG</HeadsetModel>
    <HeadsetModel>Sennheiser Dect</HeadsetModel>
    <HeadsetModel>Sennheiser Dect for Lync</HeadsetModel>
    <HeadsetModel>Sennheiser SD</HeadsetModel>
    <HeadsetModel>Sennheiser D 10</HeadsetModel>
    <HeadsetModel>Sennheiser SD for Lync</HeadsetModel>
  </AMSupportedHS>
</SeComSFSDK>
```